# Использование subprocess для автоматизации исполнения внешнего exe файла

Tags: python, subprocess

Я скачал программку для научных расчетов, которая представляет собой простой exe файл без всяких там GUI. В этой программке все нужно вбивать вручную в командную и не работает Ctrl+c/Ctrl+v. Я очень хочу научиться запускать ее из питона и автоматизировать процесс расчета. Но единственно что мне удалось это запустить мой exe при помощи

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen("C:\\...\\my.exe")
```

Я попробовал следующий наладить диалог сказав

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen("C:\\...\\my.exe", shell=True, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write("x=4\n")
proc.stdin.write("print(x)")
proc.stdout.read()
```

но он ушел в себя и молчит.

Что делать? Может я что-то не так сказал?

Comment: Приведите примеры заполнения параметров, которые та программа хочет. Желательно так: запустите в консоли, введите часть параметров и скопируйте с консоли и добавьте в вопрос

Comment: А зачем python? Нельзя просто перенаправить файл с командами на stdin программы? Типа `my.exe <commands.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было закрыть stdin. Вот два варианта решения:

первый:

```
>>> p = subprocess.Popen("C:\\...\\my.exe", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p.stdin.write('2+2\n')
>>> p.stdin.close()
>>> p.stdout.read()
'4\n'
```

и второй,

```
>>> p = subprocess.Popen("C:\\...\\my.exe", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> out, err = p.communicate(input='2+2\n')
>>> p.stdin.close()
>>> print out 
4\n
```

И нужно помнить о [рекомендации по поводу shell=True](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

Comment: 1- из вопроса не ясно как приложение параметры принимает: с командной строки, со стандартных потоков (stdin), напрямую с консоли (`ReadConsoleW()`). 2- не нужно `stderr=PIPE` использовать, если вы не читаете из потока—в общем случае это может процесс подвесить 3-  бессмысленно после `p.communicate()` вызывать `p.stdin.close()`.